# Possible to loop through and turn off ALL layers?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

The below finds my layer and shows visible property in the console, when I toggle it there from '`true`' or '`false`' it changes.

```
myApp.mapview.map.findLayerById('cool_layer');
```

[image]

But when I run the below line, I can toggle my layers on or off individually, but how could I loop through all of them, and turn them all off? I am trying tocreate a 'reset' button.

```
myApp.mapview.map.findLayerById('cool_layer').visible = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that by iterating the map layers:

```js
myApp.mapview.map.layers.items.forEach(item => {
    item.visible = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Now... could I potentially do the same with any 'filters'?

Comment: What do you mean with filters?

Comment: i.e. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-support-FeatureFilter.html